# Custom Top Donors (Contributions) report with the name of Relationship Managers

Tags: drupal, extension, developer, custom-reports

Followed the instructions on civix and built an extension, copied the Top Donors report and set up the new template. Now I see the original report. Need to modify the php so that I can pull in the name of the Relationship Managers from Relationships. Any pointers on this? Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Ok here's what I do when faced with situtations like this: check how Eileen does it:

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport

At times I'll extend one of her extended reports; it's a very well written extension.